# LOD Bias in OpenGL Textures

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

The function method glTexImage2D takes 'level' as a paremeter which represents the Level Of Detail bias. However, A texture's LOD Bias can be set using glTexParameteri and the GL_TEXTURE_LOD_BIAS target. How do these do settings for LOD Bias interact? Are they the same, and whichever is set most recently is used, or do they have different meanings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The function method glTexImage2D takes 'level' as a paremeter which represents the Level Of Detail bias.

No, it does not. The `level` parameter specifies which mipmap level you are [allocating an image for](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Texture_Storage#Direct_creation).